# How can I use AWS client components in the root layout of Next.js 14?

Tags: javascript, next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I am using Next.js 14.0.2 with the app router and I want to render the root `layout.tsx` on the server side. I am also using AWS Amplify's `ThemeProvider` and `Authenticator` component, which are client components according to my research. Therefore, I am not allowed to use them in the root layout (SSR).

Wrapping these components in a separate component like described in the Next.js documentation also didn't help. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-third-party-packages-and-providers

This is my `layout.tsx`:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next"
import { Inter } from"next/font/google"
import "../styles/globals.css"
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import React from "react";
import Providers from "@/app/Providers";
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';

import awsExports from '../aws-exports';
const existingGraphQLConfig = {
    aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint: "xxx",
    aws_appsync_region: "xxx",
    aws_appsync_authenticationType: "API_KEY",
    aws_appsync_apiKey: "xxx",
};

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
Amplify.configure(existingGraphQLConfig);

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Title",
  description: "This is the description",
}


export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

This is my `Providers.tsx`:

```
"use client"

import {Authenticator, ThemeProvider} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { studioTheme } from "../ui-components";
import React from "react";

export default function Providers({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={studioTheme}>
            <Authenticator.Provider>{children}</Authenticator.Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

In the browser console, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] 37:00.913 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
            The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
            This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

            1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
                See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

            2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

Any help regarding this problem would be much appreciated!